# How to increase memory usage to specific level for certain time duration

Tags: linux, unix

How can I reduce available free memory to certain level for specific time duration?

I've total of 16GB memory where free memory is more than 90%. I want to reduce free memory to 5% and have it in this state for about 120seconds

## to check memory usage

```
vmstat -s
```

## to reduce free memory

```
tail /dev/zero
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`stress-ng`](https://manned.org/stress-ng/fd34c972).

This line command will use 90% of your memory.

`stress-ng --vm-bytes $(awk '/MemAvailable/{printf "%d\n", $2 * 0.9;}' < /proc/meminfo)k --vm-keep -m 1`

Change the `0.9` to any value (must remain as a decimal). It signifies the percentage.